# Odoo t-field image is appearing empty to public

Tags: python, odoo, odoo-8, odoo-9

I have a simple controller when shows the people comment in the website along with their pictures. Everything works fine except the image is not appearing when the user logout.

here is my controller

```
    @http.route('/page/homepage', type='http', auth='public', website=True)
def comment_list(self):
    comments = request.env['erp.comment'].sudo().search([], limit=10)
    values = {
        'user': comments,
    }
    return request.website.render('website.homepage', values)
```

and here is the xml content

```
       <div class="ocomment-avatar">
             <span t-field="p.image" t-field-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;image&quot;, &quot;class&quot;: &quot;img-rounded&quot;}"/>
       </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use img tag.
like

```
<span>
   <img t-att-src="'p.image'" t-att-class="'img-rounded'" t-att-widget="'image'"  />
</span>
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Not working Just img icon appearing i tried to replace img with span and remove the other two span. that also didn't worked

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it was due to security reason, i add an open access rule of the module. and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

```
<img t-if="line.image_upload"
    t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,%s' % to_text(line.image_upload)"
    style="max-height: 300px;"/>
```

`line.image_upload` is the binary field

Comment: Could you add a little description to your answer.

Comment: Code only responses are discouraged on SO. consider editing to point out key bits of your answer, & how/why it solves the Op's issue.

Answer (score 0):

use t-att-src instead of span t-field tag
then it worked

Comment: Welcome! Could you explain how your answer adds something to the previous ones?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the method "image_data_uri"

```
<img t-att-src="image_data_uri(image)" />
```

They had the same problem :

https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/how-to-display-a-image-in-qweb-from-ir-attachment-table-146979